# Android Emulator connect to server

Tags: sockets, android-emulator, portforwarding

You are my last hope. I think read everything about it but I don't understand it. I have an app that opens a socket on port 90 and connects to a server on the internet. It works on my Android tablet but not in the Android emulator. I know that i have to forward the port but I don't know how. I thought the command is "redir add tcp:90:90" but this does not work.

I need the command so I can connect to an internet adress with port 90.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm i found out it works sometimes and sometimes it does not work ....
Probably a bug in the emulator.

Answer (score -1):

a client-server app, huh? ok...
this what i did with my voip client-server app.
Assuming the client is on the emulator and the server is on the same machine as the emulator.
point the client on your emulator to 10.0.2.2, have u done that? if not that may b ur problem.

read on Network Address Space at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

Comment: Yeah the client is on the emulator, but the server is not on my localhost. The server is external and i access it over the internet. I already read this article but it doesn't work or i don't understand it ...
I would really appreciate if you could tell me what exactly to write.